# electrum increase fee from command line

Tags: transaction-fees, electrum

is it possible to increase fee from command line in `electrum`? I walked through all electrum commands but can't find such command.

Comment: If `rbf=True` for the transaction I think you can increase the fee in the replacement transaction.

Comment: but with which command :)

Comment: `payto` command is used to create a transaction with one output

Comment: but transaction is already in the bitcoin network, now I need add some extra fee

Comment: If the transaction is not confirmed and RBF was enabled, you can create and broadcast another transaction to spend same UTXO with more fees

Comment: @Prayank thanks, I think you should post it as answer

Comment: I think I will have to create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum) for this because I tried something and it didn't work. Let me share in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use RBF from command line with `bumpfee` command.

It was added in this pull request: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/pull/7438